# Google Docs shared link requires login to edit document

Tags: google-docs

If I want give access to a Google Docs by sending an invitation email from Google Docs (link sharing enabled), when the recipient opens the link from the email, it only allows them to view it, and requires in bold red letters that they must log in to be able to edit it. Which is the opposite of what it said when creating the invitation: *Access:Anyone (no sign-in required) Can edit*

How to make it send an URL that works as advertised?

Details:

- I (the document owner) open the document in my browser
- I click `Share`
- click `Advanced`
- set `Who has access` to : *Anyone who has the link can* ***edit*** (that is: *Link sharing* is **On** , *Access:Anyone (no sign-in required) Can edit*)
- add email addresses to the `Invite people:` field (`Notify people` is enabled by default)
- add a message like: *This is the document we talked about...*
- click `Send`

Result:

The link sent to the recipients opens the Docs, but does not allow editing unless they log in to Google.

What I found out:

- The culprit is the `invite=xyZFOO` parameter in the URL. If it is deleted and the resulting URL opened, it works (the Docs is displayed and can be edited).
- it seems Google Docs appends this parameter to the URL in the invitation mail based on the recipient address (whether it is a Google account or not - for Google accounts it sends a "working" URL, for other it appends this *invite* parameter), but it is not consistent (or I am running out of test recipients)
- if I enable `Send a copy to myself` then the URL sent to me is always without the problematic parameter

Is there a way to "just make it work"?

In my situation asking the recipients to manipulate an URL is the same as asking them to perform brain surgery.

PS: Example links:

- works as is (allows editing without login): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zlBBvQuQ1mDF_lutpmqrAErjaZHYsxio5r5SHVtP1YE/edit?usp=sharing
- requires login to edit: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zlBBvQuQ1mDF_lutpmqrAErjaZHYsxio5r5SHVtP1YE/edit?usp=sharing_eixpa_nl&invite=CJmZ4bsF&ts=5839d305

PPS:

- Forget what I wrote in "What I found out". Suddenly both links allow access. It seems random.
- Apparently this is a very old issue, at least from 2011. See this Google forum topic: [Google Docs Insists in sign-in required even though I selected "Anyone with a Link"](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/NqyjZi_ZLjA)

PPPS: As noted in comments the links now both allow editing without logging in. I created a new test file and links for it:

- test 2 (requires login): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WvgBVQSmXoIbzPL55hsj8VnvAKC-xsr2ideDJA1rGzk/edit?invite=COW5_b4O&ts=583b0e26
- test 2 (same but with *invite* parameter deleted): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zlBBvQuQ1mDF_lutpmqrAErjaZHYsxio5r5SHVtP1YE/edit?usp=sharing_eixpa_nl&ts=5839d305

Now for me the first one requires logging in to edit, while the seconds does not. I **guess** after a while it starts to work as expected. Please someone try the second link (the one labeled "test 2 - requires login")

Comment: I was able to access both test 2 links and edit them in incognito mode without signing in my account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could not be reproduced as of 9/8/2017.

Comment: @jonsca It seems Google added and extra step if a recipient does not have a Google account: either Send an invitation ("Recipient must sign in with a Google account within 14 days to edit.") or "Send the link (no sign-in required)". So the problem is solved.

Comment: News: now (2022) both first two example links require a login, while the 3rd allows access for all (no login) and the 4th requires login. It's like random.